# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core' in Statsmodels - broken Conda environment inside Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, conda, statsmodels

I've been trying to upgrade Pandas to version 1.4.4 (was 1.4.1) inside Pycharm, with the project pointing to a Conda environment. I decided to make a new conda environment and do it that way. That was a big mess, but "something" has affected the original conda environment, which I left well alone - and rightly so. I'm trying to get the original environment in PyCharm back to executing my code. Unfortunately, I'm seeing the following. This is the kind of error that, when googling, is very bespoke to the package in question. Thus, it isn't easy to abstract anything from it.

I'm not sure what information is going to help. But I'll provide what I can when asked. Firstly, this is the error.

```
File "C:\Users\yewro\PycharmProjects\HCDD\GUI\MainGUI.py", line 3, in <module>
    from GUI.AnalysisWindow import AnalysisWindow
  File "C:\Users\yewro\PycharmProjects\HCDD\GUI\AnalysisWindow.py", line 5, in <module>
    from GUI.Controllers.AnalysisController import AnalysisController
  File "C:\Users\yewro\PycharmProjects\HCDD\GUI\Controllers\AnalysisController.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Engines.DFBuilders.CohortDFBuilder import *
  File "C:\Users\yewro\PycharmProjects\HCDD\Engines\DFBuilders\CohortDFBuilder.py", line 4, in <module>
    import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
  File "C:\Users\yewro\anaconda3\envs\HCDD\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .formulatools import handle_formula_data
  File "C:\Users\yewro\anaconda3\envs\HCDD\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\formula\formulatools.py", line 2, in <module>
    from patsy import dmatrices, NAAction
  File "C:\Users\yewro\anaconda3\envs\HCDD\lib\site-packages\patsy\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import patsy.highlevel
  File "C:\Users\yewro\anaconda3\envs\HCDD\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py", line 19, in <module>
    from patsy.design_info import DesignMatrix, DesignInfo
  File "C:\Users\yewro\anaconda3\envs\HCDD\lib\site-packages\patsy\design_info.py", line 31, in <module>
    from patsy.util import atleast_2d_column_default
  File "C:\Users\yewro\anaconda3\envs\HCDD\lib\site-packages\patsy\util.py", line 53, in <module>
    _pandas_is_categorical_dtype = getattr(pandas.core.common,
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Python is 3.9, and pandas is stuck at 1.4.1. Statsmodels is 0.13.3.

I would be so grateful for any help.

Comment: What's the `patsy` version in the environment? That's where the error originates. Possibly a version incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and report later. Paper work to do before I can go back to coding. Thanks again.

Comment: @merv patsy is 0.5.2 - sorry for the slow response—too many things to do.